# Java - Simple Tax Calculator using If and if else statements

Tags: java, if-statement, calculator, tax

Newb Java programmer here,
Why isn't this calculator calculating?

The program should input Income from the user, and then Output their Federal Tax based on the calculations.

**Federal Tax Rules:**
15% on the first $45,282 of taxable income, +
20.5% on the next $45,281 of taxable income (on the portion of taxable income over $45,282 up to
$90,563), +
26% on the next $49,825 of taxable income (on the portion of taxable income over $90,563 up to
$140,388), +

Input: 
Enter mark: 85 
Output: 
Grade is: A 
Input: 
Enter mark: 110 
Output: 
Enter a value between 0 and 100 
Input: 
Enter mark: 79.5 
Output: 
Grade is: B+ 
Input: 
Enter mark: -10 
Output: 
Enter a value between 0 and 100
29% on the next $59,612 of taxable income (on the portion of taxable income over $140,388 up to
$200,000), +
33% of taxable income over $200,000.

```
package practiceproblab4;

import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author JAVA NEWB
 */
public class PracticeProbLab4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your Income: ");
String In = sc.nextLine();
Double Income = Double.parseDouble(In);

calculateAndPrintTax(Income);
System.out.println("Your taxes are: " + TotalTax);
}

static double calculateAndPrintTax(double Income, double Tax)
{
    double tax;
    double difftax1;
    double difftax2;
    double difftax3;
    double difftax4;
    double TotalTax;

    if ((Income >= 45282) && (Income <= 200000))
    {
        if(Income<=45282)
        {
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            TotalTax = tax;
        }
        else if (Income > 45282 && Income <= 90653)
        {
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            difftax1 = (Income - 45282)* .205;
            TotalTax = tax + difftax1;
        }
        else if ((Income >90563) && (Income <= 140388))
        {
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
            difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
            TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2;
        }
        else if ((Income > 140388) && (<= 200000))
        {
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
            difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
            difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
            TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3;
        }
        else if ((Income > 200000))
        {
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
            difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
            difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
            difftax4 = (Income - 200000) * 0.33;
            TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3 + difftax4;
        }
    else ((Income > 200000))
            {    
            tax = 45282 * 0.15;
            difftax1 = (Income - 45282) * .205;
            difftax2 = (Income - 90563) * 0.26;
            difftax3 = (Income - 140388) * 0.29;
            difftax4 = (Income - 200000) * 0.33;
            TotalTax = tax + difftax1 + difftax2 + difftax3 + difftax4;
            return TotalTax;
            }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting ?

Comment: One issue that jumps out is `double TotalTax` is declared in `calculateAndPrintTax`. This means it is not visible in the `main` method when you attempt to print `TotalTax`

Comment: Another issue: `calculateAndPrintTax` needs 2 parameters, but you only pass one argument in `main`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are printing nothing here (because you didn't initialize `TotalTax` anywhere in your `main` method):

```
calculateAndPrintTax(Income);
System.out.println("Your taxes are: " + TotalTax);
```

What you have to do is declare it in main and accept the return value of your method:

```
double TotalTax;

TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income);
System.out.println("Your taxes are: " + TotalTax);
```

Also, you have to remove the return in the else part of `calculateAndPrintTax` you have to put it outside the `if/elseif/else` clause:

```
if{
 // code here
}
else if{
 // code here
}
else{
 // code here
}
return TotalTax;
```

Comment: To add on to this , you need to change calculateAndPrintTax(double Income, double Tax) to calculateAndPrintTax(double Income).

Comment: When the changes that you suggested are made, I get two errors still

Comment: TotalTax = calculateAndPrintTax(Income); is underlined in red and else ((Income > 200000)) is also underlined in red